# display form in popup wordpress jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have link for adding new record
        /add_records.php">Add New

So it opens form in new page
I want to open that form on the same page in popoup
How can I do that?
Form contents coming from different file

Answer (score 2):

In your child theme's folder create another folder called js (unless your theme already has a js folder) and within that folder create a new file called popup.js
Paste into that file the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.popup').click(function() {
     var NWin = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400');
     if (window.focus)
     {
       NWin.focus();
     }
     return false;
    });
});
```

In your child theme's functions.php add the following:

```
//* Register and Enqueue scripts for popup
function cc_popup_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'popup', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/popup.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'popup' );
 }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cc_popup_script');
```

Once you have added the code above, you can now use this in your page/post content by attaching a class of 'popup' to any link you want to open in a popup. For example

```
<a href="add_records.php?Add New" class="popup">popup example page</a>
```

It would also be easy to also make this into a plugin which should be tidier than adding to the theme.

Comment: Thank you.It is good way.But it creating new window.I dont want it as window